# Grouping MySQL Data and Formatting with PHP and CSS

Tags: php, css, mysql

FYI, I am using PHP and MySQL.

I am working on converting our spreadsheet staff rota to a more interactive online rota system.

I can get all the functions of the rota system fine, but when it comes to formatting it to make it clear of the departments and roles within each department, it is not so obvious.

I dont want to have to create a call to the database for each department and each role within the departments, but am stumped as to how to it to group the results and then output the results correctly and with the formatting I would like.

I do understand that this may be a very vague explanation of what I am trying to get to happen, and feel free to ask as many questions as you like.

I hope I make sense :-)

Have a great day

*MySQL Data*

```
ID | Name   | Dept | Role
---|--------|------|------
1  | John   | 1    | 2
2  | Steve  | 1    | 2
3  | Colin  | 1    | 3
4  | Trevor | 1    | 3
5  | Nigel  | 2    | 4
6  | Gary   | 2    | 5
```

*Desire page/table format*

```
STAFF  | ..
-------|---
John   | ..
Steve  | ..
-------|---
Colin  | ..
Trevor | ..
-------|---
TOT D1 | ..
-------|---
Nigel  | ..
-------|---
Gary   | ..
-------|---
TOT D2 | ..
```

Comment: Does your TOT stand for total count? Also what is the data that you want to show in the second column?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @JashParekh TOT does indeed stand for total count. The second (and further) column would be the days of the week and whether that staff member is in or off that day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values for each employee and the sum by department you can use the [`WITH ROLLUP` modifier of the `GROUP BY` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) with adds extra rows with the totals by each value of the grouped columns.

Supposing that you want to show the salary:

```
select coalesce(name,concat('Total D',Dept)) as Name, sum(Salary) as Salary
from Staff
group by Dept, name with rollup
having coalesce(Dept,0)!=0
```

Results:

```
|     Name | Salary |
|----------|--------|
|    Colin |  80000 |
|     John | 100000 |
|    Steve | 120000 |
|   Trevor |  40000 |
| Total D1 | 340000 |
|     Gary |  60000 |
|    Nigel |  50000 |
| Total D2 | 110000 |
```

The `HAVING` condition if for excluding the final row with the grand total, if you want that row you have to change a bit the `COALESCE()` to get the proper description:

```
select coalesce(name,concat('Total D',Dept),'Grand total') as Name, sum(Salary) as Salary
from Staff
group by Dept, name with rollup
```

Results:

```
|        Name | Salary |
|-------------|--------|
|       Colin |  80000 |
|        John | 100000 |
|       Steve | 120000 |
|      Trevor |  40000 |
|    Total D1 | 340000 |
|        Gary |  60000 |
|       Nigel |  50000 |
|    Total D2 | 110000 |
| Grand total | 450000 |
```